# Can one use Google Finance to backtest (i.e. simulate trades in the past)?

Tags: investing, shares, google-finance

Is it possible to simulate what would have happened if I started investing 10 years ago using Google Finance?

For example, If I started investing in company XYZ where I could have invested £100 a month from 2002 to 2012 and reinvesting any dividend received.

Would Google Finance work things out accurately and show me what I would have today?

Comment: Keep in mind that this wouldn't include transaction fees or other costs.

Comment: George - the yahoo or google site wouldn't, but the spreadsheet can adjust however the OP likes.

Comment: @joe Of course.  However, it doesn't mean that OP will think to do this.  Based on the way the question was asked, I thought it prudent to point that out.

Comment: oops, good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used yahoo to perform the exercise you're asking about. It allows you to download price data, month end if you wish, and by manipulating via a spreadsheet to add a column for purchases, you can easily see how your £100/mo would end after so long a time period.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Google Finance, you will get incorrect results because Google Finance does not show the dividend history. Since your requirement is that dividends are re-invested, you should use Yahoo Finance instead, downloading the historical 'adjusted' price.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add the stocks/mutual funds that you want and then you would just need to add all the transactions that you theoretically would have made.

Performing the look up on the price at each date that you would have sold or bought is quite tedious as well as adding each transaction.